# Query that filters out results if they exist in a second table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables.  First is a table `Employees` the second is `TimeCard`.  I am trying to determine when employees are not here.  Sample Tables:

[image]

So an employee name is returned if it meets the following criteria: `Status` = 1 and `Date` != '8/27/13'.  However I only want an `Employee` returned once even if they have multiple entires in the `TimeCard` table as long as they are not on a specified date.

Comment: Where's the query you've tried so far that isn't working?  What database and version are you using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.  I simplified my query and table names for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT e.employee FROM employees e 
WHERE status=1 
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM timecard t 
                 WHERE t.employee=e.employee 
                 AND t.Date = '8/27/13')
```

where `'8/27/13'` will work only, if date is a varchar column. Otherwise you should use a more standard date format like `'2013-8-27'`.

*Edit:*

In MSSQL `'8/27/13'` will actually work, but it is still not a good idea to use this notation as it is not unambiguous when smaller numbers are used, like `'5/6/7'`. Depending on who entered it (and from which country they come), this could mean either May 6 2007, or 2005 May the 7th or 5 June 2007 ...

*2. Edit*:

Evidently *not a good idea* to prepare supper while you are putting together a SQLfiddle! The whole thing was buggy. I just fixed it and, of course corrected the typo with `t.Date != '8/27/13'` sorry for the confusion! See the corrected fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26454/1

Comment: Hmm not having any results returned with this.  Perhaps I made a mistake. `SELECT e.jeempl FROM jempl e WHERE e.jeshop = '1' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM jtimd t WHERE t.jlempl = e.jeempl AND t.jldate != '8/27/13')`

Comment: Check out my SQLfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e08dc/2 here. I used simplified names to make life easier for myself ...

Comment: Change the condition to t.Date = '8/27/13' because you're looking for employees where no row with that date exist.

Comment: @dnoeth yes you fixed it for me.  This gets the results I need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.employee 
FROM employees e
LEFT JOIN timecard t ON t.employee = e.employee
WHERE e.status = 1 AND (t.date != '8/27/13' OR t.date IS NULL)
```

Comment: This will not list 'Bob' and depending on the `timcard` contents some names might appear multiple times.

Comment: That does not return duplicates.  However it is just returning the results of every `e.employee` where `e.status` = '1'  So essentially just every active employee.

Comment: @Matt Yes, of course, you are right with the duplicate issue. I overlooked the `DISTINCT` - but poor old Bob will stil not be listed ... ;-)